# Complex slicing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I am trying to perform a slice with multiple conditions without success.
Here is what my dataframe looks like

[image]

I have many countries, which names are stored as indexes. And for all those countries I have 7 different indicators, for two distinct years.

My goal is to select all the countries (and their indicators), which 'GDP per capita (constant 2005 US$')' is superior or equal than a previously defined treshold (gdp_min), OR that are named 'China', 'India', or 'Brazil'.

To do so, I have tried many different things but still cannot find a way to do it.
Here is my last try, with the error.

```
gdp_set = final_set[final_set['Indicator Name'] == 'GDP per capita (constant 2005 US$)']['2013'] >= gdp_min | final_set.loc[['China', 'India', 'Brazil']]
```

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last) ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py in
> na_logical_op(x, y, op)
> 301         #  (xint or xbool) and (yint or bool)
> --> 302         result = op(x, y)
> 303     except TypeError:
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\roperator.py in ror_(left,
> right)
> 55 def ror_(left, right):
> ---> 56     return operator.or_(right, left)
> 57
>
> TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_or' not supported for the input types, and
> the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types
> according to the casting rule ''safe''
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last) ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py in
> na_logical_op(x, y, op)
> 315             try:
> --> 316                 result = libops.scalar_binop(x, y, op)
> 317             except (
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_libs\ops.pyx in
> pandas._libs.ops.scalar_binop()
>
> ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last) ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_16016/3232205269.py in 
> ----> 1 gdp_set = final_set[final_set['Indicator Name'] == 'GDP per capita (constant 2005 US$)']['2013'] >= gdp_min |
> final_set.loc[['China', 'India', 'Brazil']]
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in
> **array_ufunc**(self, ufunc, method, *inputs, **kwargs)    2030         self, ufunc: np.ufunc, method: str, *inputs: Any, **kwargs: Any
> 2031     ):
> -> 2032         return arraylike.array_ufunc(self, ufunc, method, *inputs, **kwargs)    2033     2034     # ideally we would define this to avoid the getattr checks, but
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arraylike.py in
> array_ufunc(self, ufunc, method, *inputs, **kwargs)
> 251
> 252     # for binary ops, use our custom dunder methods
> --> 253     result = maybe_dispatch_ufunc_to_dunder_op(self, ufunc, method, *inputs, **kwargs)
> 254     if result is not NotImplemented:
> 255         return result
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_libs\ops_dispatch.pyx in
> pandas._libs.ops_dispatch.maybe_dispatch_ufunc_to_dunder_op()
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\common.py in
> new_method(self, other)
> 67         other = item_from_zerodim(other)
> 68
> ---> 69         return method(self, other)
> 70
> 71     return new_method
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arraylike.py in
> **ror**(self, other)
> 72     @unpack_zerodim_and_defer("**ror**")
> 73     def **ror**(self, other):
> ---> 74         return self.*logical_method(other, roperator.ror*)
> 75
> 76     @unpack_zerodim_and_defer("**xor**")
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in
> _arith_method(self, other, op)    6864         self, other = ops.align_method_FRAME(self, other, axis, flex=True, level=None)
> 6865
> -> 6866         new_data = self._dispatch_frame_op(other, op, axis=axis)    6867         return self._construct_result(new_data)
> 6868
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in
> _dispatch_frame_op(self, right, func, axis)    6891             # i.e. scalar, faster than checking np.ndim(right) == 0    6892
> with np.errstate(all="ignore"):
> -> 6893                 bm = self._mgr.apply(array_op, right=right)    6894             return type(self)(bm)    6895
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in
> apply(self, f, align_keys, ignore_failures, **kwargs)
> 323             try:
> 324                 if callable(f):
> --> 325                     applied = b.apply(f, **kwargs)
> 326                 else:
> 327                     applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py in
> apply(self, func, **kwargs)
> 379         """
> 380         with np.errstate(all="ignore"):
> --> 381             result = func(self.values, **kwargs)
> 382
> 383         return self._split_op_result(result)
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py in
> logical_op(left, right, op)
> 390         filler = fill_int if is_self_int_dtype and is_other_int_dtype else fill_bool
> 391
> --> 392         res_values = na_logical_op(lvalues, rvalues, op)
> 393         # error: Cannot call function of unknown type
> 394         res_values = filler(res_values)  # type: ignore[operator]
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py in
> na_logical_op(x, y, op)
> 323             ) as err:
> 324                 typ = type(y).**name**
> --> 325                 raise TypeError(
> 326                     f"Cannot perform '{op.**name**}' with a dtyped [{x.dtype}] array "
> 327                     f"and scalar of type [{typ}]"
>
> TypeError: Cannot perform 'ror_' with a dtyped [float64] array and
> scalar of type [bool]

The error is very long but from what I may understand, the problem comes from the second condition which is not compatible with an 'OR' ( | ).

Do you guys have any idea how I could do what I intend to please? The only thing I can see is to create a new column with current index names, so that filtering might work with the OR condition.

Comment: first do not share your data as an image but rather as a text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, use:

```py
m1 = final_set['Indicator Name'].eq('GDP per capita (constant 2005 US$)')
m2 = fina_set['2013'] >= gdp_min

countries = list(final_set.index[m1 & m2])+['China', 'India', 'Brazil']

gdp_set = final_set[final_set.index.isin(countries)]
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED:**

This should do what you're asking:

```py
gdp_set = final_set.loc[list(
    {'China', 'India', 'Brazil'} | 
    set(final_set[((final_set['Indicator Name'] == 'GDP per capita (constant 2005 US$)') & 
        (final_set['2013'] >= gdp_min))].index)
    )]
```

Explanation:

- create a `set` containing the union of `'China', 'India', 'Brazil'` with the `set` of any index values (i.e., `Country Name` values) for rows where value of `Indicator Name` matches the target and value of `2013` column  is at least as large as `gdp_min`.
- filter `final_set` on the countries in this `set` converted to a `list` and put the resulting dataframe in `gdp_set`.

---

Full test code:

```py
import pandas as pd
final_set = pd.DataFrame({
'Country Name':['Andorra']*6 + ['Argentina']*4 + ['China']*2 + ['India']*2 + ['Brazil']*2,
'Indicator Name':[f'Indicator {i}' for i in range(1, 6)] + ['GDP per capita (constant 2005 US$)'] + [f'Indicator {i}' for i in range(1, 4)] + ['GDP per capita (constant 2005 US$)'] + [f'Indicator {i}'if i % 2 else 'GDP per capita (constant 2005 US$)' for i in range(1,7)],
'2002': [10000.0/2]*6 + [15000.0/2]*4 + [8000.0/2]*6,
'2013': [10000.0]*6 + [15000.0]*4 + [8000.0]*6,
'Currency Unit':['Euro']*6 + ['Argentine peso']*4 + ['RMB']*2 + ['INR']*2 + ['Brazilian real']*2,
'Region':['Europe & Central Asia']*6 + ['Latin America & Caribbean']*4 + ['Asia']*2 + ['South Asia']*2 + ['Latin America & Caribbean']*2,
'GDP per capita (constant 2005 US$)': [10000.0]*6 + [15000.0]*4 + [8000.0]*6
}).set_index('Country Name')
print(final_set)
gdp_min = 14000.0

gdp_set = final_set.loc[list(
    {'China', 'India', 'Brazil'} | 
    set(final_set[((final_set['Indicator Name'] == 'GDP per capita (constant 2005 US$)') & 
        (final_set['2013'] >= gdp_min))].index)
    )]
print(gdp_set)
```

Input:

```
                                  Indicator Name    2002     2013   Currency Unit                     Region  GDP per capita (constant 2005 US$)
Country Name
Andorra                              Indicator 1  5000.0  10000.0            Euro      Europe & Central Asia                             10000.0
Andorra                              Indicator 2  5000.0  10000.0            Euro      Europe & Central Asia                             10000.0
Andorra                              Indicator 3  5000.0  10000.0            Euro      Europe & Central Asia                             10000.0
Andorra                              Indicator 4  5000.0  10000.0            Euro      Europe & Central Asia                             10000.0
Andorra                              Indicator 5  5000.0  10000.0            Euro      Europe & Central Asia                             10000.0
Andorra       GDP per capita (constant 2005 US$)  5000.0  10000.0            Euro      Europe & Central Asia                             10000.0
Argentina                            Indicator 1  7500.0  15000.0  Argentine peso  Latin America & Caribbean                             15000.0
Argentina                            Indicator 2  7500.0  15000.0  Argentine peso  Latin America & Caribbean                             15000.0
Argentina                            Indicator 3  7500.0  15000.0  Argentine peso  Latin America & Caribbean                             15000.0
Argentina     GDP per capita (constant 2005 US$)  7500.0  15000.0  Argentine peso  Latin America & Caribbean                             15000.0
China                                Indicator 1  4000.0   8000.0             RMB                       Asia                              8000.0
China         GDP per capita (constant 2005 US$)  4000.0   8000.0             RMB                       Asia                              8000.0
India                                Indicator 3  4000.0   8000.0             INR                 South Asia                              8000.0
India         GDP per capita (constant 2005 US$)  4000.0   8000.0             INR                 South Asia                              8000.0
Brazil                               Indicator 5  4000.0   8000.0  Brazilian real  Latin America & Caribbean                              8000.0
Brazil        GDP per capita (constant 2005 US$)  4000.0   8000.0  Brazilian real  Latin America & Caribbean                              8000.0
```

Output:

```
                                  Indicator Name    2002     2013   Currency Unit                     Region  GDP per capita (constant 2005 US$)
Country Name
Brazil                               Indicator 5  4000.0   8000.0  Brazilian real  Latin America & Caribbean                              8000.0
Brazil        GDP per capita (constant 2005 US$)  4000.0   8000.0  Brazilian real  Latin America & Caribbean                              8000.0
China                                Indicator 1  4000.0   8000.0             RMB                       Asia                              8000.0
China         GDP per capita (constant 2005 US$)  4000.0   8000.0             RMB                       Asia                              8000.0
India                                Indicator 3  4000.0   8000.0             INR                 South Asia                              8000.0
India         GDP per capita (constant 2005 US$)  4000.0   8000.0             INR                 South Asia                              8000.0
Argentina                            Indicator 1  7500.0  15000.0  Argentine peso  Latin America & Caribbean                             15000.0
Argentina                            Indicator 2  7500.0  15000.0  Argentine peso  Latin America & Caribbean                             15000.0
Argentina                            Indicator 3  7500.0  15000.0  Argentine peso  Latin America & Caribbean                             15000.0
Argentina     GDP per capita (constant 2005 US$)  7500.0  15000.0  Argentine peso  Latin America & Caribbean                             15000.0
```

Comment: That also works perfectly fine thank you! One funny thing is that it shuffles the resulting set.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a query?

```
# min GDP (I used an example number
gdp_min = 3000.0

# Country name set.
countries = {"China", "India", "Brazil"}

# Create string expression to evaluate on DataFrame.
# Note: Backticks should be used for non-standard pandas field names 
# (including names that begin with a numerical value.
expression = f"(`Indicator Name` == 'GDP per capita (constant 2005 US$)' & `2013` >= {gdp_min})"
# Add each country name as 'or' clause for second part of expression.
expression += "or (" + " or ".join([f"`Country Name` == '{n}'" for n in countries]) + ")"

# Collect resulting DataFrame to new variable.
gdp_set = final_set.query(expression)
```

Comment: I am totally unaware of how queries work so thank you for giving me this solution Mark. It'll be a starting point for learning this!